# Java - cumulative sum of integer input doesnt work in while loop

Tags: java, cumulative-sum

Im having trouble figuring out why my code doesnt work. First off, Im new to Java so bear with me.
The task is:
Write a program that reads a sequence of integer inputs and prints the cumulative totals. If the input is 1 7 2 9, the program should print 1 8 10 19.

```
package lektion05forb;

    import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Lars
 */
public class P52LoopsC 
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Numbers: ");
    double cumulative_sum = 0;
    String output_cumulative_sum= "";

    while (input.hasNextDouble())
    {
        double input_number = input.nextDouble();
        cumulative_sum += input_number;
        output_cumulative_sum += String.format("%s ", String.valueOf(cumulative_sum));
        break;
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println(output_cumulative_sum);
}

}
```

When I input a sequence of numbers like 3 4 5 8 2, it returns with 34582, instead of the cumulative sum of the numbers. Can anyone explain why, and how i can fix it so it returns the cumulative total of the sequence?

Comment: what is not working? what are you expecting from the code to output?

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: ´@thegauravmahawar - it should output the cumulative sum of a sequence of inputs, but if i input 3 4 7 2 1 it just outputs 34721.

Comment: First of all, remove the `break` in your loop. You also don't need to format the sum in every iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer with a `double`

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Numbers: ");
    double cumulativeSum = 0;

    String line = input.nextLine();
    
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
    
    for(String number : numbers){
        cumulativeSum += Double.parseDouble(number);
        System.out.println(cumulativeSum);
    }
    
    input.close();
}
```

Input:

> Numbers: 1 7 2 9

Output:

> 1.0
>
> 8.0
>
> 10.0
>
> 19.0

Here is the, perhaps superior, solution with `Integer`

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Numbers: ");
    Integer cumulativeSum = 0;

    String line = input.nextLine();
    
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
    
    for(String number : numbers){
        cumulativeSum += Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println(cumulativeSum);
    }
    
    input.close();
}
```

Input:

> Numbers: 1 7 2 9

Output:

> 1
>
> 8
>
> 10
>
> 19

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `break`from the while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `do-while`, because this way, the loop will execute at least once, in the code you have written, <s>the loop never executes, because the `input.hasNextDouble()` is null, because there was no input from user yet after the initialization.</s> (Actually, the loop does execute in case of the scanner, but is generally considered a bad design to execute while-loop without having the control variable implicitly defined and initialized.)

the code goes like this

```
do {
        double input_number = input.nextDouble();
        cumulative_sum += input_number;
        output_cumulative_sum += String.format("%s ", String.valueOf(cumulative_sum));

    }  while (input.hasNextDouble());
```

Also, never put `break;` inside while statement, this way it will loop only once even if the argument is true after first run, because you break out of the loop.